# Верстка html css под iphone

Tags: xhtml, html, css

Помогите пожалуйста! Как можно верстать страницу под iphone, но чтобы это не затрагивало ipad.

Пробую вот так писать отдельный css, все хорошо, но на ipade лезут краказябры разные!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iphone4.css" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)">
```

Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему бы Вам не использовать медиа запросы CSS? С ними все просто и это избавит Вас от необходимости делать запросы средствами PHP или jQuery.

Почитать можете [здесь](http://bootstrap-ru.com/scaffolding.php). Думаю, что у Вас не возникнет сложностей ... сделайте по аналогии и будет Вам счастье!

Удачи.

Answer (score 2):

Как вам идея с помощью PHP или Jquery выделить пользователей iPhone и подсунуть им нужный стиль?

```
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
определяет iPhone или iPod)
```

Ну или другими способами. Но суть предложения такова, сначала понять что за устройство, потом дать нужные стили и параметры использования этих стилей..

Comment: А куда подставить этот jquery navigator? В body или в head или в css&